# Pandas: How can I use str.extractall with another column as the pattern input?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use another column as my pattern for str.extract/all? The below example uses a hardcoded pattern, but I want Pandas to look at every row in the `Pattern` column and use that pattern for its extraction search.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Pattern": ['a|c'],
                   "Files": ['a.csv, b.csv, c.csv, d.csv']})

# explode
df['Files'] = df['Files'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode(['Files'])

# extract
df['Expected'] = df['Files'].str.extract(r'([a|d])')  # hardcoded

# expected
  Pattern   Files Expected
0     a|d   a.csv        a
0     a|d   b.csv      NaN
0     a|d   c.csv      NaN
0     a|d   d.csv        d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since :

> **Series.str.extract**(pat, flags=0,
> expand=True)
> Extract capture groups in the regex pat as columns in a DataFrame.
>
> For each subject string in the Series, **extract groups from the first
> match of regular expression pat**.
>
> *Source* : [[pandas.docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)]

I would use [`search`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/re.html#re.search) with [`group`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) inside a *listcomp*.

```
import re

df["Expected"] = [re.search(f"({p})", s).group(1)
                  if re.search(f"({p})", s) else None
                  for s,p in zip(df["Files"], df["Pattern"])]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  Pattern   Files Expected
0     a|d   a.csv        a
0     a|d   b.csv     None
0     a|d   c.csv     None
0     a|d   d.csv        d
```